# C: Transforming 'while' loops into 'for' loops

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

Our codebase contains a few loops of the form `while((*assignment*) *condition*)`, for example:

```
while((c = *s++) != '\0') {...}

while((i = getNext()) != NULL) {...}
```

Unfortunately these are causing the compiler to emit an "assignment in condition" warning, which I would like to get rid of. My plan is to transform the `while` loops into `for` loops of the form for(*assignment*; *condition*; *assignment*), for example:

```
for(c = *s++; c != '\0'; c = *s++) {...}

for(i = getNext(); i != 0; i = getNext()) {...}
```

Is this transformation valid? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: For the `while` loops you show, GCC does not complain about an 'assignment in condition'.  If you omitted the `!= '\0'` or `!= NULL` condition _and_ the extra level of parentheses (e.g. `while (c = *s++)`) then GCC warns.  Otherwise, it does not...so which compiler are you using on which platform with which options?

Comment: Turn off the warnings with a #pragma.  You're changing code that isn't broken so you run the risk of introducing bugs.

Comment: @Paulpro You're badly confused and completely wrong. The warnings are for the original code in the `while` loops, not the transformed `for` loops which don't get warnings, and even if they did your change would have no relevance.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 4):

The transformations are valid, yes, but they result in code that's harder to maintain, simply because there are *two* places you have to change the assignment.

I would be more inclined to figure out how to turn off that particular warning (even if it's localised with something like the `gcc` `#pragma warning` pragma) since it is, after all, perfectly valid C code, both syntactically and (in this case) semantically.

Comment: +1 for the 'harder to maintain' comment — that should govern.  It's the DRY principle again: Don't Repeat Yourself. The expansions violate the DRY principle.

Comment: +1 for the second comment about turning off the warning.  Changing code that isn't broken could introduce bugs if mistakes are made.

Comment: ("you you" (below my threshold))

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd write the first loop like this:

```
for (char c; (c = *s) != '\0'; ++s)
{
    // ...
}
```

This makes it clear that the `s` is the thing that's being incremented. You can also omit the `!= '\0'`, which is implicit.

I'd keep the second loop as a `while` loop, or at least leave the assignment-inside-conditional. Maybe like this, to minimize scope pollution:

```
for (iterator i; i = getNext(); )
{
    // ...
}
```

I personally find it quite acceptable to have part of the per-loop activity happening inside the conditional; that's natural for things like `std::cin >> n` and `std::getline(file, line)`, too.

Comment: Unfortunately both of these suggestions still cause the "assignment in condition" warning. Although I agree that it may be "acceptable to have part of the per-loop activity happening inside the conditional", this compiler disagrees.

Comment: @user2121571: Hm, well, the iterator loop would probably look different anyway, like `for (iterator it = container.first(); it.has_next(); it = it.next())`, or something equivalent, so there should only be an actual, read-only conditional check...

Comment: @user2121571 Then turn off that warning in your compiler configuration. if you can't do that then your compiler is a heap of low quality junk.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of loops is correct your transformation is completely valid, but this transformation seems to be a lot harder to read than the while loop. Just do the initialization before the `while` loop and then increment at the end of the loop to get rid of the warning.

```
c = *s++;
while(c != '\0') 
{
    ...
    c = *s++;
}
```

Comment: That has all the evils of the OP's transformation and then some.

Comment: hmm can you explain to me the more part?

Comment: This is not equivalent (think `continue`)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated what your compiler is, but any compiler of quality allows such a warning to be turned off. But if you can't manage that:

```
for(;;)
{
    c = *s++;
    if (c == '\0') break;
    ...
}
```

is equivalent and is more general. Likewise:

```
for(;;)
{
    i = getNext();
    if (!i) break;
    ...
}
```

In many cases, better than the first one (but not equivalent) is:

```
for(;; s++)
{
    c = *s;
    if (c == '\0') break;
    ...
}
```

These are more verbose and ugly, but they are much better than your transformation that repeats the code, which is fragile and error-prone.